# UITableViewCell height incorrect, sizeToFit sizes incorrectly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to create a custom UITableViewCell, and having issues with the cell frame having the proper height. This is troubling because the cell sizes correctly for iPhones 4s/5s running iOS 8.4, but not for iPhones 6/6+ running the same OS.

Chaos ensues around calling `sizeToFit` on `messageLabel`. Some of the labels almost appear to have extra, blank lines below, but clearly are not as tall as the cell makes them out to be.

Below is the custom cell. The label that appears to cause the trouble is the messageLabel. To view the frames of the labels, `let borders = true`

```
//
//  NotesTableViewCell.swift
//  urchin
//
//  Created by Ethan Look on 6/17/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Tidepool. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

let noteCellHeight: CGFloat = 128
let noteCellInset: CGFloat = 16
let labelSpacing: CGFloat = 6

class NoteCell: UITableViewCell {

    let borders = false

    var cellHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat()

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    let timedateLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var messageLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    func configureWithNote(note: Note) {

        usernameLabel.text = note.user!.fullName
        usernameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 17.5)!
        usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        usernameLabel.sizeToFit()
        let usernameX = noteCellInset
        let usernameY = noteCellInset
        usernameLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: usernameX, y: usernameY)

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE M.d.yy h:mm a"
        var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(note.timestamp)
        dateString = dateString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("PM", withString: "pm", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        dateString = dateString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("AM", withString: "am", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        timedateLabel.text = dateString
        timedateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 12.5)!
        timedateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        timedateLabel.sizeToFit()
        let timedateX = contentView.frame.width - (noteCellInset + timedateLabel.frame.width)
        let timedateY = usernameLabel.frame.midY - timedateLabel.frame.height / 2
        timedateLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: timedateX, y: timedateY)

        messageLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width - 2 * noteCellInset, height: CGFloat.max)
        let hashtagBolder = HashtagBolder()
        let attributedText = hashtagBolder.boldHashtags(note.messagetext)
        messageLabel.attributedText = attributedText
        messageLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()
        let messageX = noteCellInset
        let messageY = usernameLabel.frame.maxY + 2 * labelSpacing
        messageLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: messageX, y: messageY)

        contentView.addSubview(usernameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(timedateLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(messageLabel)

        cellHeight = noteCellInset + usernameLabel.frame.height + 2 * labelSpacing + messageLabel.frame.height + noteCellInset

        if (borders) {
            usernameLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
            usernameLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

            timedateLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
            timedateLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

            messageLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
            messageLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

            self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        }

        self.contentView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: cellHeight)
    }  
}
```

And `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       let cell = NoteCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
       cell.configureWithNote(notes[indexPath.row])
       return cell.cellHeight
}
```

The project is open source and [on Github](https://github.com/tidepool-org/urchin), so feel free to clone the repository and check out all of the code yourself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an entirely new cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, I simply create the UI elements that determine the cell height (usernameLabel and messageLabel), size them appropriately with `sizeToFit`, then do a simple calculation to determine the cell height.

By doing this, I never create a new cell which is later dequeued.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let usernameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    usernameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 17.5)!
    usernameLabel.text = notes[indexPath.row].user!.fullName
    usernameLabel.sizeToFit()

    let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 2*noteCellInset, height: CGFloat.max))
    let hashtagBolder = HashtagBolder()
    let attributedText = hashtagBolder.boldHashtags(notes[indexPath.row].messagetext)
    messageLabel.attributedText = attributedText
    messageLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    messageLabel.sizeToFit()

    let cellHeight = noteCellInset + usernameLabel.frame.height + 2 * labelSpacing + messageLabel.frame.height + noteCellInset

    return cellHeight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do it that way because `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath)` is called first and the value you return is used to create the cell that you will dequeue in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath)`.  The cell can't set its own size because by the time it could do so (e.g. `awakeFromNib` or `prepareForResuse`), the table view will already have a height value for it.  There are some whacky workarounds for this that I've used, but it's easier to just use self-sizing table view cells.

Check it:
http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/